# How to install .net framework 4.5 after download completes from web using innosetup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to download and install the .netframework 4.5 from web using innosetup.
I followed these procedure,
1.I downloaded and installed InnoTools Downloader.
2.In InitializeWizard i declared

```
itd_init;
itd_addfile('http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225702',expandconstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'));
itd_downloadafter(10);
```

Where 10 is the curpageId.
And in

```
NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer) i added ,
 if CurPageId=104 then begin

     `filecopy(expandconstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'),expandconstant('{app}\dotNetFx`45_Full_x86_x64.exe'),false);
     end
```

**Now what i need to do is,i want to check whether .net framework 4.5 is installed in my pc or not, using the function how can i check **,

```
function Framework45IsNotInstalled(): Boolean;
var
 bVer4x5: Boolean;
 bSuccess: Boolean;
 iInstalled: Cardinal;
 strVersion: String;
 iPos: Cardinal;
 ErrorCode: Integer;

begin
 Result := True;
 bVer4x5 := False;

 bSuccess := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Install', iInstalled);
 if (1 = iInstalled) AND (True = bSuccess) then
  begin
    bSuccess := RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Version', strVersion);
    if (True = bSuccess) then
     Begin
        iPos := Pos('4.5.', strVersion);
        if (0 < iPos) then bVer4x5 := True;

     End
  end;

 if (True = bVer4x5) then begin
    Result := False;
end;
end;
```

**where i need to check this condition, in my side downloading and installing of .netframework 4.5 is happening fine,the only condition i need to check  whether .net framework 4.5 is installed or not,before calling  this **itd_downloadafter(10)Where 10 is the curpageId.****.
Then only download wont happen, if .netframework is already exist in my enduser pc.
How can i achieve this task? any ideas?

Comment: Try to [`search here`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Binno-setup%5D+detect+.NET+framework).

Comment: hi TLama,i want to call Framework45IsNotInstalled function in InitializeWizard,because in initializewizard only i declared  itd_downloadafter(10), i want to call framework45IsNotInstaller function before it_downloadafter(10). how it is possible?

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to conditionally download .NET framework installer only if it's not already installed from `InitializeWizard` event method; if so, then [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/e8ic0uKq).

Comment: Thank you very much TLama, this is what i am trying .Finally i got it.

Comment: Don't hardcode page ids.  They may change in future versions of Inno or your own script.  Use the defined constants for standard pages or the Id property for your own pages.

Comment: ok what is the default page id for installer screen in innosetup,i can notice that after click install button i noted the page id as 10,so i hardcoded it.How to customize the default installer page or what is the constant for installer page?

Comment: The page constants are listed on [`this page`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#PageID). The installing page has the `wpInstalling` constant. And @Miral is right, the page ID values may vary, so it's definitely better to use them instead of hardcoding values.

Comment: @TLama: About your Pastebin code example, shouldn't `if not Framework45IsNotInstalled` be `if Framework45IsNotInstalled` because the code block is downloading the framework?

Comment: @RandomEngy, yes, it should be so. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The release version numbers in the registry for .NET 4.5 are highlighted in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Your code needs to be modified to look at the '*Release*' key in the registry as specified in the MDSN article above and can be simplified just to check for this value.

```
function Framework45IsNotInstalled(): Boolean;
  var
   bSuccess: Boolean;
   regVersion: Cardinal;

  begin
    Result := True;

    bSuccess := RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', regVersion);
    if (True = bSuccess) and (regVersion >= 378389) then begin
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

For a more complete example of checking .NET version numbers with Inno Setup you can also look at the code in this very useful article: http://kynosarges.org/DotNetVersion.html

Comment: Simply `Result := not (RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Release', regVersion) and (regVersion >= 378389));`.

Comment: Thanks @TLama, my Pascal is a bit rusty these days :)

Comment: Seems to me that `RegQueryDWordValue` should be used instead, and there's an extra `end` in the code. I tried to edit your answer myself hoping you wouldn't mind, but it was rejected. It was helpful nevertheless, thanks!